# Question - if $\sum_{k=1}^n c_k\cdot5^k$ is convergent so $\sum_{k=1}^n c_k\cdot(-2)^k$ is also convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I think that's a wrong argument but I can't think of a counterexample.

How about $\sum_{k=1}^n c_k\cdot(-5)^k$? Is it convergent?

Comment: **Hint:** $\sum c_k 5^k$ being convergent implies $c_k 5^k \to 0$.

Comment: if you don't sum to infty the convergence is trivial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given that the radius of convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k x^k$ is at least $5$. That is more than $2$.

Comment: ok, so because (-2) is in (-5, 5) I can say that $\sum_{i=0}^n c_k*(-2)^k$ is also convergent?

Comment: What if we were talking about $\sum_{i=0}^n c_k*(-5)^k$? Is it convergent?

Comment: no not necessary, take $$c_k= (-1)^k 5^{-k}\cdot \frac{1}{k}$$

Comment: @homiee, either you mean *finite* sums, for which the questions of convergence and divergence are rather boring and perhaps even irrelevant, or you better put an $\,\infty\,$ in the upper limit of all those sums.

Comment: @homiee, it might be. The classical case is $\sum_{n \ge 0} x^n$, with convergence radius 1. It converges for $x = -1$, and diverges for $x = 1$. In your case, if the $c_k$ are non-negative, that series does converge too.